# Como escalar una fila de un dataframe a la anterior?

Tags: python, pandas

Me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de escalar datos de una fila a la anterior, ejemplo en siguiente dataframe

Entreada

```
INGRESO_503 tipo_procedimiento FEC_FOLIO_503 CAMB_INGRESO CAMB_PROCE CAMB_FECHA
1543983 intubacion 2021-05-25 
1543983 extubacion 2021-05-26 1543983 extubacion 2021-05-26
1543983 extubacion 2021-05-28 1543983 extubacion 2021-05-28
1543983 extubacion 2021-05-29 1543983 extubacion 2021-05-29
1544039 intubacion 2021-05-25 
1562391 intubacion 2021-07-26 
1562391 extubacion 2021-07-26 1562391 extubacion 2021-07-26
1562391 extubacion 2021-07-26 1562391 extubacion 2021-07-26
1562402 intubacion 2021-07-26 
1562402 extubacion 2021-07-26 1562402 extubacion 2021-07-26
```

SALIDA: que sus ultimas tres columnas suban suban una fila

```
INGRESO_503 tipo_procedimiento  FEC_FOLIO_503   CAMB_INGRESO    CAMB_PROCE  CAMB_FECHA
1543983 intubacion  2021-05-25  1543983 extubacion  2021-05-26
1543983 extubacion  2021-05-26  1543983 extubacion  2021-05-28
1543983 extubacion  2021-05-28  1543983 extubacion  2021-05-29
1543983 extubacion  2021-05-29          
1544039 intubacion  2021-05-25          
1562391 intubacion  2021-07-26  1562391 extubacion  2021-07-26
1562391 extubacion  2021-07-26  1562391 extubacion  2021-07-26
1562391 extubacion  2021-07-26          
1562402 intubacion  2021-07-26  1562402 extubacion  2021-07-26
1562402 extubacion  2021-07-26
```

Comment: No entiendo muy bien la parte "que sus ultimas tres columnas suban suban una fila" - ¿El objetivo que perseguís es que estén ordenados por número de INGRESO_503?

Comment: no necesariamente tiene que estar ordenado por ingreso solo que las de las 6 colubnas las tres ultimas suban un escaño o una fila

Comment: Como quieres que una columna suba una fila? Solo puedes subir filas con respecto a filas y columnas con respecto a columnas

Comment: si que escalen con respecto a las otras tres columnas que están de primero

Comment: sería bueno que pongas un ejemplo de la salida esperada

Comment: uno lo realiza en Excel manual pero pues me gustaría saber si hay algún método para hacer eso con código

Comment: se me ocurre un forma rara de hacerlo, pero sigo sin entender muy bien lo que quieres y por eso pido el ejemplo de la salida esperada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La mejor forma que se me ocurrió de hacerlo es convirtiendo cada columna ( que se desea *subir*) en una lista y borrar su primer elemento y luego reemplazar dicha columna por la lista *truncada*

```py
#convertimos a lista y agarramos desde el primer elemento
camb_ing = df["CAMB_INGRESO"].tolist()[1:]
camb_proce = df["CAMB_PROCE"].tolist()[1:]
camb_fecha = df["CAMB_FECHA"].tolist()[1:]

#reemplazmos la columna
df["CAMB_INGRESO"] = camb_ing+['']
df["CAMB_PROCE"] = camb_proce+['']
df["CAMB_FECHA"] = camb_fecha+['']
```

Al momento de hacer la nueva asignación hacemos `camb_ing+['']` por que la lista debe ser del mismo tamaño que el numero de columnas y al haber *borrado* la primera nos queda una menos. Si quieres eliminar más tendrás que agregar el mismo número de columnas que haz eliminado, para ello te puede servir una comprensión de lista.

Comment: Funciono perfecto, excelente